# Forecast Category field is missing in Summer 14

Tags: forecast

In the sandbox which is Summer 14 we are not able to see the Forecast category field under opportunities object, whereas in Prod org which is still Spring 14 we are able to see this field... Also in a totally different org (Sandbox) which is also in Summer 14 we can see the Forecast category field. It is wierd why we are not able to see the Forecast category field in our sandbox org which is in Summer 14 version..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I have a sandbox in Summer 14 that suddenly stopped recognizing the ForecastCategoryName field today. My class doesn't compile anymore when it did yesterday. It's like forecasting was turned off, yet it is still enabled under the settings.

Comment: Do you guys happen to remember what CS instances this was on? Just received a report from a customer of our code failing in Sandbox (CS10, currently on W15) and Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName is missing, as are OpportunityStage.ForecastCategory and OpportunityStage.ForecastCategoryName

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty weird, have you checked the field level security  for the Forecast field? If that's not the problem you should log a case with support.